# Use PivotTable with Left Outer Join

Tags: mysql, pivot-table, entity-attribute-value

I'm fairly new to MySQL.
Put simply, I want to turn each "meta_key" value into a column of the resulting table.

I've got two tables with the following schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `frmt_form_entry` (
  `entry_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `entry_type` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
  `form_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `is_spam` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`entry_id`),
  KEY `entry_is_spam` (`is_spam`),
  KEY `entry_type` (`entry_type`),
  KEY `entry_form_id` (`form_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;


CREATE TABLE `frmt_form_entry_meta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `entry_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `meta_key` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `date_updated` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
  KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`),
  KEY `meta_entry_id` (`entry_id`),
  KEY `meta_key_object` (`entry_id`,`meta_key`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```

There exist multiple "meta entries" per "form entry":

```sql
INSERT INTO `frmt_form_entry` (`entry_id`, `entry_type`, `form_id`, `is_spam`, `date_created`)
VALUES
    (1, 'custom-forms', 3744, 0, '2020-08-14 13:00:32');



INSERT INTO `frmt_form_entry_meta` (`meta_id`, `entry_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`, `date_created`, `date_updated`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'text-7', 'Foreign Legal Form', '2020-08-14 13:00:32', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
    (2, 1, 'name-1', 'Test Name', '2020-08-14 13:00:32', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
    (3, 1, 'address-1', 'a:6:{s:7:\"country\";s:0:\"\";s:4:\"city\";s:0:\"\";s:5:\"state\";s:0:\"\";s:3:\"zip\";s:0:\"\";s:14:\"street_address\";s:0:\"\";s:12:\"address_line\";s:0:\"\";}', '2020-08-14 13:00:32', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
    (4, 1, 'address-2', 'a:6:{s:7:\"country\";s:0:\"\";s:4:\"city\";s:0:\"\";s:5:\"state\";s:0:\"\";s:3:\"zip\";s:0:\"\";s:14:\"street_address\";s:0:\"\";s:12:\"address_line\";s:0:\"\";}', '2020-08-14 13:00:32', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
    (5, 1, 'address-3', 'a:6:{s:7:\"country\";s:0:\"\";s:4:\"city\";s:0:\"\";s:5:\"state\";s:0:\"\";s:3:\"zip\";s:0:\"\";s:14:\"street_address\";s:0:\"\";s:12:\"address_line\";s:0:\"\";}', '2020-08-14 13:00:32', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
    (6, 1, '_forminator_user_ip', '8.8.8.8', '2020-08-14 13:00:32', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
    (7, 1, 'stripe-1', 'a:6:{s:4:\"mode\";s:4:\"test\";s:6:\"status\";s:7:\"success\";s:6:\"amount\";s:2:\"0\";s:8:\"currency\";s:3:\"\";s:14:\"transaction_id\";s:27:\"\";s:16:\"transaction_link\";s:70:\"\";}', '2020-08-14 13:00:32', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
```

I'd like to create a Pivot Table with the same number of rows as there are rows in the frmt_form_entry table (1 in this case).

I want each meta key to be a column name of that pivot table. Since each meta key can only exist once per entry_id, I won't need to concatenate the meta values of multiple fields for the same meta key.

This is the expected output:

```
entry_id    entry_type  form_id is_spam date_created     text-7       name-1   address-1    address-2    address-3. _forminator_user_ip   stripe-1
1   custom-forms    3744    0   2020-08-14 13:00:32 Foreign Legal Form  Test Name [...]
```

What I've tried so far:

```sql
SELECT entries.*,
CASE WHEN meta.`meta_key`='stripe-1' 
    THEN meta.`meta_value`
    ELSE NULL 
    END
    AS stripe,
CASE WHEN meta.`meta_key`='text-7' 
    THEN meta.`meta_value`
    ELSE NULL 
    END
    AS text7,
CASE WHEN meta.`meta_key`='_forminator_user_ip' 
    THEN meta.`meta_value`
    ELSE NULL 
    END
    AS user_ip,
CASE WHEN meta.`meta_key`='address-1' 
    THEN meta.`meta_value`
    ELSE NULL 
    END
    AS address1,
CASE WHEN meta.`meta_key`='address-2' 
    THEN meta.`meta_value`
    ELSE NULL 
    END
    AS address2,
CASE WHEN meta.`meta_key`='address-3' 
    THEN meta.`meta_value`
    ELSE NULL 
    END
    AS address3,
CASE WHEN meta.`meta_key`='name-1' 
    THEN meta.`meta_value`
    ELSE NULL 
    END
    AS name1
FROM frmt_form_entry entries
LEFT OUTER JOIN frmt_form_entry_meta meta
ON entries.entry_id = meta.entry_id
```

However, this feels wrong and messy and it doesn't give the expected result (it creates one entry per meta value).

Is there an easy, better way to turn each "meta_key" value into a column of the resulting table?

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't know what you meant. Added them. @Strawberry

Comment: When you say 'rows as there are', do you mean 'same number of rows as there are columns'

Comment: No, same number of rows in the PivotTable as there are rows in the `frmt_form_entry` table (so 1 row for the given sample data). @Strawberry

Comment: `MAX(CASE...END) address1` etc

Comment: Looking good! It still looks messy though, doesn't it? Is there a way without having to explicitly specify each meta key? What do you think about performance? @Strawberry

Comment: Well, you could always handle issues of data display in application code. Another option is to outer join the table as often as necessary, which is probably fractionally faster, but your method is considerably more elegant than that.

Comment: I didn't mean the data, I meant the SQL - it didn't seem too elegant to me but good to know! @Strawberry

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry, it actually does not give the expected result - this will always ever show one row. Add an entry to the `frmt_form_entry ` table and it won't show in the result.

Comment: You need a GROUP BY clause too

Comment: Definitely the fastest reply I've ever got and pretty accurate - that did it! Feel free to provide an answer btw so I can give you the credit. @Strawberry

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I am going to be rather blunt.  "Entry-Attribute-Value" is a great schema pattern for textbooks, but not for the real world.

EAV is especially inappropriate for columns that exist for all the items.  If "every" location has an address, city, etc, then make them columns.  Simpler.  More efficient.  (In the case of `address_1` and an optional `address_2`, use `NULL` to indicate optionality.)  Do you ever need the parts of an address for searching or filtering?  If not, then simply have a single column for the whole "address".

Reserve "meta" for attributes that are usually *not* present.  As a separate discussion we can discuss the benefits/drawbacks of using a single JSON column for such.  Or how to do searching with `FULLTEXT`.

Do you really need the `date_created` and `date_updated`?

The 4 indexes you have on the `meta` table are quite inefficient.  See this for tips on improving it:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

Comment: While I do appreciate your answer and the constructive criticism (it helps!), I am not responsible for the database design nor am I in a position to make any changes to it. And I'd add that this is not quite an answer to what the question is about.